# Where to declare a public object which refer to a VB object?

Tags: vb.net, object, global, public, declare

First time that I use Visual Studio and VB.net.

Could someone explain to me where to declare a public object which refers to a VB object ?

This code works fine :

```
Public Class Form1

    Private ThePen As New System.Drawing.Pen(Color.Red)

    Private Sub Line(A As Point, y As Point)
       Dim NewGraphic As Graphics = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics()
       NewGraphic.DrawLine(ThePen, A, B)
       NewGraphic.Dispose()
    End Sub

End Class
```

But I would like to declare only one time in public

```
Dim NewGraphic As Graphics = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics()
```

I tried to declare it at the beginning, but it seem that my object `PictureBox1` is not yet loaded (so, can't access `PictureBox1.CreateGraphics()`)

So I tried in

```
Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
```

But I can't declare public variable inside :(

Comment: You don't have to use `CreateGraphics()` at all. Call that code from the Handler of the `PictureBox.Paint` event. Modify your `Line` method to accept a Graphics object (`Private Sub Line(g as Graphics, A As Point, B As Point)`), then pass the `e.Graphics` object of the `PaintEventArgs` argument of the `Paint` handler. (Btw, you didn't specify where the Point values are set. Also, you're using a `B` Point, not `y`, which doesn't exist in that method). Don't dispose of the Graphics object your method receives, that's taken care of *somewhere else*.

Answer (score 1):

You should pretty much NEVER call `CreateGraphics`. Draw on a control in its `Paint` event handler or, if appropriate, create a custom control and override the `OnPaint` method. Store the data that represents the drawing in one or more fields and, whenever you want to change the drawing, set those fields and call `Invalidate` on the control.

```vb
Private lineStart As Point
Private lineEnd As Point

Private Sub DrawLine(start As Point, [end] as Point)
    lineStart = start
    lineEnd = [end]
    PictureBox1.Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, lineStart, lineEnd)
End Sub
```

Generally speaking, it is preferable to specify the area to invalidate rather than not specifying an argument and invalidating the entire control. It is actually painting the pixels to the screen that is the slow part so it is preferable to keep that to a minimum. I'll leave that part to you but you may like to check [this](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?426684) out for more info. Note that, if you're moving a line, you'd need to invalidate the area that contained the old line and the area that will contain the new line. You can call `Invalidate` multiple times with different areas in such cases, or you can combine the areas into one `Region` and call it once.

Answer (score 0):

So different view but interesting !

I'm unable to test it :(
There's a problem with e. object in

```
e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, lineStart, lineEnd)
```

BC30456 Visual Basic 'Graphics' is not a member of 'EventArgs'.